# SSRS Datasource Escape Password

Tags: ssrs, authentication

I am using a dynamic datasource inside a SSRS report to display detailed metrics about an instance. This dynamic datasource uses a SQL Login to connect to each instance listed by this report.

The password includes a backtick and a dollar sign "abcdef`$ghijk"

[image]

[image]

And as a result, I believe that only a portion of the password is getting sent to SQL Server.

Can someone please tell me how to escape the password here? 
I have already tried backslashes and quotes.

Windows authentication can't be used, because the instances are spread across two different domains